# Query Result widget on Dashboard does not allow me to zoom-in into work item's details

Tags: azure-devops

I built a dashboard that uses query results widget showing open work items across departments in the firm. But I cannot double click on the item and bring up the detail window anymore. I used to be able to do that couple of weeks ago. Is this some new 'feature' of Devops?

I am administrator on the project so I should have all the rights. Running query in the query editor works as expected (meaning I can zoom in on item's detail by double clicking)

Comment: I guess it would be too hard to understand without screenshots for this kind of question. Could you please provide better description, screenshots etc?

Comment: The fix release has been deployed now. Does your query widget recover the normal work now?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not the new "feature" of Azure Devops.

Until now, we have been received several issue report tickets which are all encounter the same issue with you. There seems some problem occurred, and our team is trying to fixed this issue.

You can follow this DC ticket to get the latest progress about this issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/625883/azure-devops-dashboard-queries-no-longer-clickable.html

You can also vote this issue report ticket, so that we can archive the issue affected.